# Interstitial Ad won't show up on android emulator after completing all of the steps for creating an ad

Tags: android, kotlin, interstitial

I've already successfully implemented test ads, however, I'm ready to test real ads now. I've followed the steps for registering and creating ads.

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

I've tried starting over again with following the tutorial, however, I still fail to get a real interstitial ad to pop up. I already registered my app and the ad unit 3 days ago.

Here is the android manifest metadata.

```
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.ca-app-pub-9137217174806568~9043276963"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-9137217174806568~9043276963"/>
```

Here is the interstitial ad.

```
    // set up ads
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-9137217174806568~9043276963")

    mInterstitialAd = InterstitialAd(this)
    mInterstitialAd.adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-9137217174806568/2038884913"
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())

    mInterstitialAd.adListener = object : AdListener() {

        private fun showToast(message: String) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onAdClicked() {
            super.onAdClicked()
        }
        override fun onAdClosed() {
            val nextIntent = Intent(applicationContext, ExamineEarnings::class.java)

            startActivity(nextIntent)
            activityState.switchStates(activityState.EXAMINE)
            timeTracker.reset()
            pauseButtonTracker.switchPauseButtonStateToResume()
            finish()

        }

        override fun onAdFailedToLoad(p0: Int) {
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(p0)
            showToast(String.format("Ad failed to load with error code %d.", p0))

            Log.e("themessage", p0.toString())

        }
    }
```

Both the app id and the unit ad id are correct. However, when I test it out in the Android emulator, the app fails to load with status code 0.

Comment: have you registered payment method in your admob account ?

Comment: No. I haven’t. I’ll try that next.

Comment: i dont think it will work without that